# Foxpro "Too many files open "

Tags: windows, file, windows-xp, foxpro

I am trying to run a foxpro application on windows 98.

When i run the application it displays error message "Too many Files open" and then terminates.

I have changed configuration in config.sys, I put Files=255 and Buffers=99. but problem not solved.

Help

Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, this might be impossible to solve without knowing the inner workings of the application.  Is this an application that would reasonably require more than 255 files to be open at once?  (I assume that you rebooted after editing config.sys).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look through the suggestions here: [PRB: How to Resolve "Too Many Files Open" Error](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/87690)

Also you need to restart the PC after config.sys changes.

Answer (score 1):

In `Config.Sys` you should add:

```
files=240

buffers=60
```

That's enough.
http://kabarislamia.com/2015/07/01/how-to-edit-autoexec-nt-and-config-nt-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 0):

Try these following options based on similar scenario:

1. Double-check config.sys and make sure files/buffers are appropriate.
2. Make sure users don't accidentally start two copies of the application.
3. Run the app in protected memory space
4. Make sure the machine doesn't have a bunch of windows TSR's loaded.